# struts2 <s:select...> tag

Tags: java, struts2

I have simple user registration form. In which i am puting city as a  tag. Here drop down box value coming from city master table from mysql database.

But when i storing whole user registration values, i m not be able to fetch currently selected city value. Can anyone help me...? My user registration form contains :

```
<s:form action="UserAction" >
        <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name" />
        <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" />

        <s:radio name="sex" label="Sex" list="{'M','F'}" />

        <s:select list="cities" key="cities.name"  listValue="name">
        </s:select>

        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution after writing following code :

```
            <s:select list="cities" name="city">
            <s:iterator value="cities">
            </s:iterator>
        </s:select>
```

And at the time of insertion through DAO, it will automatically fetching all the value from bean.

Comment: Actually, i haven't use any request or session object, so no getParamter() or getAttribute() function has been used.

Comment: May be, but the fact is all those are there in request context as parameters. Struts hides that from you.

Answer (score 1):

Give your list the exact name what you have in your bean, in your case **city**. It should start working now.

Comment: But i have passing this page to UserAction.action Java Page. So, can UserAction be act as a servlet ? Because right now my UserAction is simple Java Class. No HttpRequest object is created in UserAction.

Comment: So, how are you getting the other fields, for example name and age?

Comment: Oh... its all automagically going there. Sorry edited the post. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In your action class you are probably have an attribute based on the select tag. When you set this value add an annotation above the method signature.

Something like:

```
@RequiredStringValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, message = "Please select a value", fieldName = "select")
```

This should sort you out. This can also be done within the struts.xml file in a fairly similar way.

Cheers
Nathan